# Disable screen touch in android on call

Tags: android, touch, call, voip, proximity

I am working on a calling screen where I need to enable and disable touch events on the screen while the user is on a call.

For this I implement SensorEventListener on my activity and override the onSensorChanged() method:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
        if(sensorEvent.values[0] == 0) { //Sleep
            sleepScreen(true);
        } else { //Wake
            sleepScreen(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my sleepScreen() method:

```
protected void sleepScreen(boolean on){
    if(on == true) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
    } else {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
    }

}
```

The FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE works fine disabling touch events. However, I am not able to re-enable the touch events again.

Pls help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**STEP 1:** Add this in onCreate before calling setContentView()

```
int powerValue = 0x00000020;

    try {
        powerValue = PowerManager.class.getClass().getField("PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK").getInt(null);
    } catch (Throwable ignored) {
    }

    mPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(field, getLocalClassName());
```

**STEP 2:** Override the method by implementing SensorEventListener

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
        if (sensorEvent.values[0] == 0) { //Sleep
            sleepScreen(true);
        } else { //Wake
            sleepScreen(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**STEP 3:**  Include this method to disable screen lock

```
protected void sleepScreen(boolean on) {

        if (on == true) {
            if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                mWakeLock.acquire();
            }
        } else {
            if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                mWakeLock.release();
            }
        }
}
```

**STEP 4:** Add the wake lock permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Hi, what should the mPowerManager be declared as?

Answer (score 0):

When acquiring wake lock acquire with [PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK) flag . It will handle the screen off and on automatically.

> Wake lock level: Turns the screen off when the proximity sensor activates.
>
> If the proximity sensor detects that an object is nearby, the screen turns off immediately. Shortly after the object moves away, the screen turns on again.
> Source: developer.android.com

Eg.

```
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock= powerManager.newWakeLock((PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "WakeLock:TAG");
```